YUIMA: Drift and diffusion parameters must be different?

I am currently working with the Yuima package and trying the estimate the parameters of a CARMA(p,q) model to real data. Using the eacf function of the TSA package a ARMA (2,1) process is recommended and fits pretty well.
Now with the YUIMA package there are a lot of significant lags in the ACF function of the increments and I get the following warning massage:
"YUIMA: Drift and diffusion parameters must be different. Doing
joint estimation, asymptotic theory may not hold true."
 eacf(Residual_diff,ar.max = 4, ma.max = 4)
carma.mod<-setCarma(p=2,q=1,loc.par=NULL)
par.carma<-list(a1=1.1,a2=0.7,b0=10,b1=5)
dataresi = setData(Residual_diff, delta = 1/288)
my.yuima <- setYuima(data = dataresi , model = carma.mod)
testfit <- qmle(my.yuima, start=par.carma,Est.Incr="Incr")
summary(testfit)
inc = testfit@Incr.Lev
plot(acf(as.numeric(inc)))

Can someone help me?
PS. The data is travel, time measured in loops of 5 minutes

since, no one answered, I would email stefano iacus, the author of the package. He's quite generous and kind.
